# How to give custom layout to overflow menu items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am using Toolbar as a action bar in my application. I don't know how to give custom layout to overflow items. I know how to give custom layout to action bar menu items but don't know how to give custom layout to overflow menu items.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I want to give custom textview to this Settings item.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest on this?